# Is there a spaghetti detector available that doesn't limit the cameras framerate and resolution?

Tags: camera, spaghetti-detector

I am searching for a spaghetti detector that can pause my printer when spaghetti is detected, especially one that does not limit the framerate and resolution of my cameras, like Obico does. That is basically the reason I don't use Obico because it makes my cameras almost unusable for other purposes.

Also, I rather want a self hosted option without subscription per printer.